# WP Customize js api preview refresh event

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to implement dependent fields in wordpress customizer.

I have 3 radio buttons to show either the text field or textarea or another one depending on radio value.

Everything work well except when I type something in one of the fields fields and the preview refreshes the hidden field shows up.

My idea is to listen for the preview refresh event and trigger my fields toggle function to keep the proper fields hidden, but I cannot catch the preview refresh event.

Do you guys know how to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Rafal

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you already tried, and can you include the relevant code in your question so that we can help? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.